# codeigniter 404 error at root web site

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to setup codeigniter for our website.

if I want the main page to be http://example.com

and my folder structure looks like this:

```
public_html\
  application\
  common\
  system\
```

how do I setup codeigniter to show the page when going to http://example.com? I'm getting a 404 error when viewing it.

I edited config.php, but im not sure what to put for my base url.

my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

my routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "HomeController";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

my HomeController.php

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('HomeModel');
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $data['result'] = $this->HomeModel->function1();
    $this->load->view('index', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');

}
```

my HomeModel.php

```
<?php

class HomeModel extends CI_Model{

    public function index()
    {

    }

    public function function1()
    {
    $query = $this->db->get('work_orders');
        //return $query->result();
    return $query->result_array();

    }
}
```

Comment: Let me know one thing, is index page working properly or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT2:

Edit your default_controller from HomeController to homecontroller Like this:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "homecontroller";
```

and rename (if needed) your controller from HomeController.php to homecontroller.php and in your Controller itself call it Homecontroller.

Do the same for the model. call it homemodel.php (or home_model.php) in your directory and Call it Homemodel in your model itself.

Also clear your browser cache.

---

EDIT1:

Rename your model. I guess you called your model HomeModel.php. just call it home_model.php. this should fix your problem.

---

Your .htaccess file should look like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^LoginTut.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|table-images|js|robots\.txt|css|captcha)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
 ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

This is just copied from my server and it works great.

After then, change your default_controller to:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "the default controller";
```

and if public_html is a folder you created your index page should be:

```
$config['index_page'] = "public_html/";
```

otherwise leave it blank. (if it's your server's httpdocs)

should work :)

Comment: hmm still doesnt work, what is weird is this doesnt work:
http://gtechforce.com

but if you view a difference controller like:
http://gtechforce.com/Company/add

that page works fine.

Comment: the problem is within your model. when i type gtechforce.com/Homecontroller I get the error `An Error Was Encountered

Unable to locate the model you have specified: homemodel`

Comment: Your HomeModel isn't working. is there model called HomeModel?

Comment: yes there is, i added it to my question if you want to see what it contains

Comment: You forgot the ?> at the end of your model.

Comment: ty, i added that but that still didn't fix the issue.

Comment: It looks like your HomeModel is in another folder then in models/ do you have a subdirectory with your HomeModel in it?

Comment: Rename your model in model/ to home_model.php Your model name cannot have the same name as how you called it in your model itself.

Comment: wait a sec, my controller is called HomeController and located in the controllers folder, my model is called HomeModel and located in the models folder, from my reading on the guides, this is the default way of doing it. Also, i dont have a subdirectory in Models. this is a fresh install i havent modified any folders

Comment: i tried your suggestion of changing the HomeModel.php to home_model.php and its the same results

Comment: Just comment out your function1 for a second and try it. then we can see if it's a fault with routing or with the model.

Comment: more importanlty how come when i go to http://gtechforce.com it says:
404 page cant be found, yet when i go to:
http://gtechforce.com/Company/add  it works

Comment: just outcomment the line `$data['result'] = $this->HomeModel->function1();` too.

Comment: ok so now the home controller works: http://gtechforce.com/Home
but http://gtechforce.com still shows 404 error

Comment: You need to check the following things. 1( is your index_page set to `""` (empty) 2( do you call your default_controller as homecontroller instead of HomeController? (or Home as you did now) 3( did you set your base_url? like : `$config['base_url'] = 'http://gtechforce.com/';`

Comment: yes index_page is set to ''  yes default controller is Home. and yes base url is gtechforce.com

Comment: ya the config has an example that i followed.

Comment: post all your code you have now in routes/config/controller/model. so I can look at it in one look.

Answer (score 0):

At your **router.php** in **config folder** there is an line

```
$route['default_controller'] = "your controller name";
```

add your controller that you want to display defaultly

Answer (score 0):

You can make base_url empty:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

Try this working .htaccess conf:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

IF nothing helps then hosting doesn't support mod_rewrite apache module